# Android Spinner : go to next item upon clicking the button

Tags: android, spinner

as indicated in the title I want the spinner to proceed in the next item upon clicking the OK button.

BTW the spinner items was fetched in mysql Database.

For example I have these items

"Jeffrey Oliveras"

"Wendy Lixardo"

"Mc Salinas"

and the first selection is " Jeffrey Oliveras" then upon clicking the okay button it will automatically proceed to "Wendy Lizardo" 
any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in your Button Onclicklistener

> if(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() < spinner.getAdapter().getCount()){
>
> ```
>      spinner.setSelection(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
> ```
>
> }

Hope it work.

Comment: Hello sir it works but it crashed when the last item is selected

Comment: You have to check position of your spinner every time you click and only perform this if you are not on last position. 
Also please Vote up this answer to Help Others who were finding the same solution

Comment: @AmniX i have the same problem.. but i am facing a problem, like i have more then 100 items in spinner when i click on Button it will display the other item not the first one...